# Laravel 5.1 one form two submit buttons

Tags: php, forms, laravel-5

I am using Laravel 5.1, and I would like to make a form with two submit buttons - Save and Save draft.

But when I post my form I have all the fields except the submit value.

I have read that Laravel won't put the submit button value in the POST when the form was sent via ajax, so could you please help me how to do this?

I have tried some code as below:

```
{!! Form::open(['url' => 'offer/create', 'method' => 'post', 'id' => 'offer-create']) !!}

....
here are my fields
....

{!! Form::submit( 'Save', ['class' => 'btn btn-default', 'name' => 'save']) !!}

{!! Form::submit( 'Save draft', ['class' => 'btn btn-default', 'name' => 'save-draft']) !!}
```

In my routes.php I have:

```
Route::controller('offer', 'OfferController');
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you provide more information? How is this question related to AJAX? As Laravel itself does not put anything into the `$_POST` array, can you explain further how you've checked whether one of these buttons is submitted?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

you can use the same name and different value attribute for the submit buttons

//  example:

```
{!! Form::submit( 'Save', ['class' => 'btn btn-default', 'name' => 'submitbutton', 'value' => 'save'])!!}

{!! Form::submit( 'Save draft', ['class' => 'btn btn-default', 'name' => 'submitbutton', 'value' => 'save-draft']) !!}
```

//  Controller:

```
switch($request->submitbutton) {

    case 'save': 
        //action save here
    break;

    case 'save-draft': 
        //action for save-draft here
    break;
}
```

Comment: this will generte the button name but not the button value so this will not work

Comment: it is worked for me .... If we changed the name =>'submit' this will not worked but if set then name => submitbutton its working as well

Answer (score 0):

One of the best way is using an input with hidden type , then on clicking button append value to that input and get that value in request params in controller side .
And then using if and else condition run your query.

This is hidden input:

```
<input id="submittype" type="hidden" name="submit_type" value=""></input>
```

This is the submit button div :

```
    <div class="text-right">
                <button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" onclick="saveandexit()" type="submit">@lang('save &amp; exit')</button>
                <button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" onclick="save()" type="submit">@lang('save')</button>
            <div>

This is script:
        <script>
        function save() {
              document.getElementById("submittype").value = "save";
           }
        function saveandexit() {
            document.getElementById("submittype").value = "save-and-exit";
        }
        </script>
    @endsection
```

And , then get in controller function:

dd($request->all());