# Bootstrap CSS: align two forms buttons

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, laravel

I'm using **Bootstrap** and **Laravel**.

I would like to align two buttons "Update" and "Delete" next to each other.

BUT the **Delete button** has its own route and fields. So I created two forms.

Of course, the **Delete button** is now below the **Update button**.

***Question: How can I make them next to each other instead?***

I think a form inside of a form is not standard. Plus, it actually messes with the fields being sent.

Are there CSS rules I could apply for this to work?

I created a JSFiddle if you want to try it out: https://jsfiddle.net/0e5jk8yr/

```
<form method="post" action="/route1">
    <!-- More code here -->
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="field1" class="required">Field #1</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="field1" name="field1" value="value">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Update</button>
</form>
<form method="post" action="/route2">
    <!-- More code here -->
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
</form>
```

If it's not possible with CSS, feel free to comment and suggest UI design for item update/deletion.

Thanks to everyone reading and trying to figure this out.

**Side note:** I'm tagging this as Laravel, in case someone knows tricks I could use with Laravel/Blade for forms leading to deletion.

If CSS doesn't work, one solution would be to use only one form leading to `update()`, then call the `destroy()` method if the delete button was pressed.

Comment: Haven't worked on laravel but I am pretty sure you don't have to make two form for two separate actions. You can do this by naming the buttons. You can check this link.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39205820/laravel-5-1-one-form-two-submit-buttons

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Method 1**

If you want to keep the way it is right now you can give the forms the property of `display: inline;`.

```css
form {    
    display: inline;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://bootswatch.com/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<form method="post" action="/route1">
    <!-- More code here -->
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="field1" class="required">Field #1</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="field1" name="field1" value="value">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Update</button>
</form>
<form method="post" action="route2" id="form2">
    <!-- More code here -->
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
</form>
```

**Method 2**

However, having two forms is not necessary because you can give the inputs a name attribute and then call the functions with the name. So when the form is submitted it will either return `$_POST['submit']` or `$_POST['delete']`.

```
<form method="post" action="/route1">
    <!-- More code here -->
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="field1" class="required">Field #1</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="field1" name="field1" value="value">
    </div>
    <button name="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Update</button>
    <button name="delete" type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```css
#form2 {    
    position: absolute;
    top: 74px;
    left: 80px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://bootswatch.com/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<form method="post" action="/route1">
    <!-- More code here -->
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="field1" class="required">Field #1</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="field1" name="field1" value="value">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Update</button>
</form>
<form method="post" action="route2" id="form2">
    <!-- More code here -->
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Or like this:

```
.btn-danger {
  position: absolute;
  top: -33px;
  left: 90px;
 }
form {
  position: relative;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/0e5jk8yr/1/

Answer (score 0):

Here is your corrected code. Please check it

```
<form method="post" action="/route1">
    <!-- More code here -->
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="field1" class="required">Field #1</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="field1" name="field1" value="value">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Update</button>
    <!-- More code here -->
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
</form>
```